# MFMailComposeViewController can cancel but nothing else is editable

Tags: ios, objective-c, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

!!!Note the code works, the device needed rebooting for whatever reason after reboot it worked fine.

I use the following code to launch the email composer.

but nothing is editable on the this view controller though I can dismiss it using "Cancel" button.

the application is a storyboard based application and i've tried launching it from different parts of the application getting the same result. including the root table view controller.

I've even tried remove all of the attachemnts, subject and email body but its the same result

what could be wrong?

```
if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]){
    [doc generatePDF];
    NSMutableData *pdfData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfMappedFile:[doc pdfFilePath]];
    MFMailComposeViewController* mailviewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mailviewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [mailviewController setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES]; 

    [mailviewController setSubject:doc.documentName];
    [mailviewController addAttachmentData:pdfData mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.pdf", doc.documentName]];
    [self presentViewController:mailviewController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: Where's the code to actually display `mailviewController`?

Comment: @rmaddy added presentation code in question

Comment: test your code on iOS 6.1 ,works fine with "[foo presentViewController:mailviewController animated:YES completion:NULL]", so show more of your code to us.

Comment: @rmaddy my iPhone has 6.1.4

Comment: what other code would you want. this code is being run either from a button in table view cell or a button on toolbar/navbar

Comment: strange works in simulator !!! rebooting device

Comment: amazing all it took was to reboot device.